# How to wait until firebase save all data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java2, rx-android

I need some help with async tasks and Firebase. I need to save **n** itens on Firebase Realtime database, but I don't know how to deal with the callback.

Here's my code:

```
 TagRepository tagRepository = new TagRepository();
    for (Tag tag : databaseTags){
        if (user.getTags().containsKey(tag.getId())){
            Completable completable = tagRepository.saveUserOnTag(String.valueOf(tag.getId()), user.getUid());
        }else{
            tagRepository.removeUserOnTag(String.valueOf(tag.getId()), user.getUid());
        }
    }

  public Completable saveUserOnTag(String idTag, String userUid) {
    return io.reactivex.Completable.create(emitter->{
        reference.child(idTag).child("users/").child(userUid).setValue(true).addOnCompleteListener(task -> emitter.onComplete());
    });
}
```

If I use an callback on this method, the callback will be called **n** times, so I don't have any idea how to know when all of them are already saved so I can proceed.

I was trying something with Completable as you can see on the method, but I really don't know how to deal with it. There is any easy way to save all data at same time or to control all data that are being saved??

Comment: You could first collect all you items and save them in a single update like its shown [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't know Rx, but here is a way to insert all the data in one API call. The `onComplete()` method is the update complete callback.

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
for (Tag tag : databaseTags){
    if (user.getTags().containsKey(tag.getId())){
        values.put(idTag + "/users/" + userUid, true);
    }else{
        tagRepository.removeUserOnTag(String.valueOf(tag.getId()), user.getUid());
    }
}

reference.updateChildren(values, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        // all data saved, do next action
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), you can use simultaneous updates.

> Using those paths, you can perform simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a single call to `updateChildren()`. Simultaneous updates made this way are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was searching everywhere on google but didn't checked the official documentarion, shame on me

Comment: I understand. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could try updating firebase data synchronously using `Tasks.await`

Change the `saveUserOnTag` method as follows and try

```
public Completable saveUserOnTag (String idTag, String userUid){
        return io.reactivex.Completable.create(emitter -> {
            Tasks.await(reference.child(idTag).child("users/").child(userUid).setValue(true));
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
```

Comment: But using this code, how can i know when all values are updated?

Comment: It will block on a task and get the result synchronously. Which means it will come to the next line when it succeeds. This is useful when  your program is already executing in a background thread. Make sure that `Tasks.await` you are not doing from the Android main thread. For details : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#blocking

Comment: Oh this is actually pretty nice, thank you for the explanation